# What kind of algorithm is well suited for optimizing seat allocation in opera house?

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

So i have an opera houses with 10 rows and 10 columns of seats (Total :100). Each seat is allocated a preference value Aij. The preference value is halved if the group do not get seats in same row. Eg: If a reservation in opera house is for 5 people and only 2 can be accommodated in top row and 3 in next row, the preference value is actually halved for each seat. There are total of n reservations with 'n' > 100 seats. What will the best way to maximize the customer preference (n *Aij).If it can be done by linear programming, how should the equation look like.

Comment: Horrible question (according to SOs rules). You did not provide any information at all. We got no idea about constraints and objectives (which matter). Despite the fact, that this question does not qualify for beeing asked on SO: Mixed-integer Programming, Constraint-programming and Hybrids of these are typically used.

Comment: ... Read a book abount Operational Research or similar? Your answer is *that* broad.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. I have added more details regarding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not trivial to model as a MIP.

I gave it a try using a main binary variable `x(i,j,g,r)` where `(i,j)` is the row and column of the seat assigned to group `g`. The set `r` is `{singlerow,multiplerows}` to indicate whether the group is sitting in the same row.

Not sure if this is a particular good formulation, but it seems to work. Below are the equations I used:

[image]

I assumed that there are a number of groups `g` that each have a size. A group gets all seats it needs or it is not getting any seats.
I suspect that a constraint programming approach could be easier.

Conclusion: it can be done using a MIP formulation but it is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  What does "card(i)" refer to in the above equations?  Did you use a online solver to solve these constraints and test it out? If so can you tell me which one did you use?

Comment: `card(i)` indicates the number of elements (cardinality) of set `i`, in other words the number of rows. Yes, of course I tried it out, but not using an online tool.